# Fields based dynamic mapping elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Can I use wildcard pattern to determine index analyzer for elasticsearch?

For example:
"properties":

```
{ 
    "0_*" : {"type": "string", "index_analyzer": "standard" } , 
    "1_*" : {"type": "string", "index_analyzer": "my_analyzer"}
}
```

So now if there is a new field when I index the document like

```
{
    "0_title" : "some string", // should use standard analyzer
    "1_title" : "my anazlyer string" // should use my_analyzer
}
```

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , all you need to use is the index template.
You can find more information on dynamic template [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-root-object-type.html#_dynamic_templates)
Using index template , you can inject a rule as follows -

```
{
  "person": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "template_0": {
          "match": "0_*",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "string",
            "index_analyzer": "standard"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "template_1": {
          "match": "1_*",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "string",
            "index_analyzer": "my_analyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```